# If ${x_{n}}$ is a real sequence satisfying a certain condition, then which of the following is true

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that $\{x_{n}\}$ is a sequence of real numbers satisfying the following. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists positive integer $n_{0}$ such that $\left |x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right |$<$\epsilon, \ \forall$ $n \geq n_{0}$. Then sequence ${x_{n}}$ is

> 1). Bounded but not necessarily Cauchy
>
> 2). Cauchy but not necessarily bounded
>
> 3). Convergent
>
> 4). Not necessarily bounded

Solution I tried:

According to the given condition in question this sequence is Cauchy,then option 1 and 2 can be rejected because in 1 it is not Cauchy and in 2 it is not bounded. I am confused that the answer is actually 4 how?

Please help

Comment: Who said it is Cauchy in the first place?

Comment: the condition in the question

Comment: No, it doesn't say that. Look again at your condition and Cauchy condition. They are not the same. There is a very subtle difference.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is **not** Cauchy. The Cauchy condition is far stronger than merely requiring differences of consecutive terms to be less than $\epsilon$!

To recap, the Cauchy condition requires $|x_m - x_n| < \epsilon$ for all $m, n > n_0$ and not just $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n > n_0$. Notice: in the actual Cauchy condition, there is an extra integer $m$ variable whereas in your condition, **$m$ is kept fixed at $n+1$**. Unfortunately, keeping $m$ fixed at $n+1$ is too weak a condition to guarantee anything like convergence or even boundedness.

Indeed, consider $x_n = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Then $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}| = \frac{1}{n+1}$. So for any given $\epsilon > 0$, you can find an integer $n_0 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ to guarantee that consecutive terms have differences less than $\epsilon$ for all integers $n > n_0$. But the $x_n$'s are partial sums of the harmonic series and hence they are not even bounded let alone Cauchy.

Comment: Thankyou ,but in wikipidia the defination of cauchy sequence is same as in question

Comment: @gauravsaini No it is not. Look carefully at the edit of my answer where I put Wikipedia's definition and your's side by side.

Comment: but n+1=m can be condition,or differnence in m and n should be greater then 1?

Comment: @gauravsaini In the original Cauchy condition, $m$ can be $n +1, n+2, n+3, \ldots$ and even more values (even $n - 1, n - 2$ may be possible). As long as $m > n_0$, it is fine.

Comment: thnx ,now i understand it

Comment: @gauravsaini If you think I answered your question appropriately, consider accepting my answer...